Prettier in VSCode - Fails to format files
I get the follow error log while formatting the typescript file. I am using VSCode with formatting snippet extension.
I have checked the doc, but cannot find any solution.
["ERROR" - 12:32:27] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'printDocToDebug') 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'printDocToDebug')     
at src/main/core.js (/Users/davidlau/arbor/arbor-newspresso-frontend/node_modules/prettier/index.js:8787:9)     
at __require (/Users/davidlau/arbor/arbor-newspresso-frontend/node_modules/prettier/index.js:1748:51)     
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/davidlau/arbor/arbor-newspresso-frontend/node_modules/prettier/index.js:38168:12)     
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:14)     
at Object..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1326:10)     
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:32)     
at node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:12     
at Function._load (node:electron/js2c/node_init:2:13357)     
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1150:19)     
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:121:18) 

["ERROR" - 12:32:51] Error handling text editor change 
["ERROR" - 12:32:51] Invalid version Error: Invalid version     
at t.isAboveV3 (/Users/davidlau/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-10.4.0/dist/extension.js:1:24917)     
at t.default.getSelectors (/Users/davidlau/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-10.4.0/dist/extension.js:1:11745)     
at t.default.handleActiveTextEditorChanged (/Users/davidlau/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-10.4.0/dist/extension.js:1:11131)

I have updated to the latest version, but it is still not working.

I think you need to change the version of Prettier in package.json (this should resolve the error: "Invalid version Error: Invalid version") and downgrade VS Code to get Prettier working. This solution worked for me.
But try downgrading VS Code first. Maybe this will be enough.
I followed this YouTube video to downgrade VS Code to version 1.87: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9dhQm-9IbHA
Here are the versions I have in package.json:

prettier: ^2.8.8

on my local machine:

node: v18.18.0
npm: v10.7.0

